# Opening .djvu files from emacs links

Tags: org-mode, pdf

I use an `org` file called `books.org` to store all the information about my books, including the location of the files (`.pdf` or `.djvu`). Usually I open these files directly from Emacs by pressing `C-c o`. This works like a charm with `.pdf` which are opened in Evince because I added this lines in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (delete '("\\.pdf\\'" . default) org-file-apps)
     (add-to-list 'org-file-apps '("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince %s"))))
```

but not with `.djvu` which are not opened even if Evince can handle both filetypes. Do you know how I can tell to Emacs to use Evince to open these files?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a minimal working example of your org file? Maybe that helps for giving an answer.

Comment: Do you think it is useful? Basically it is just an org link to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this construction in my .emacs init-file (for djvu I prefer Okular, but you may use Evince as well):

```
;; Files association
(setq org-file-apps
    '((auto-mode . emacs)
    ("\\.x?html?\\'" . "firefox %s")
    ("\\.odp\\'" . "libreoffice \"%s\"")
    ("\\.doc\\'" . "libreoffice \"%s\"")
    ("\\.pdf\\'" . "okular \"%s\"")
    ("\\.pdf::\\([0-9]+\\)\\'" . "okular \"%s\" -p %1")
    ("\\.djvu\\'" . "okular \"%s\"")
    ("\\.djvu::\\([0-9]+\\)\\'" . "okular \"%s\" -p %1")))
```

And after that I may use links to file:

```
file:/data/file.djvu
```

Оr link to page of file:

```
file:/data/file.djvu::90
```

Comment: I would suggest to improve the answer by removing the part of the code not directly related with the question.